# How to update in-disk Cookies database immediately?

Tags: .net, session, cookies, awesomium

I have embedded a WebControl in a Windows Forms application to access a server-side page, which is available after a login. Normally, when the user logs in, the application (written in RoR) creates a cookie on the client-side. I am using CookieStore (Rails session store) for storing the session data on the client side. Additionally, I am using a web session provider, set up with a specific data path, to store the session on disk. To add to the issue, I am sharing that data path among several web session providers.

Now, my problem is that if the user logs out by clicking the logout link, the page is updated fine. The user can no longer perform operations that require authentication. However, as I can see the Cookies database does not get updated immediately (I see it from the file's modification date, as well as from the cookie value which stays the same). I am guessing some in-memory storage is updated first, which is then dumped into disk. I can't quite determine when, but I notice that after some time (seemingly randomly) the Cookies database is updated on disk. However, this still creates a problem, because if the user closes the application immediately after logging out, and the Cookies database hasn't updated yet, then it would have a reference to the old cookie. Expectedly, **when the user opens the application again, he will be displayed as logged in**. I know this could be **partly** mitigated by storing sessions on the server side, but I would prefer to keep things this way.

So, my question is: Is there a way to force an automatic "Cookies" database update on disk?

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same problem.  I've checked to ensure that Dispose is being called per Awesomium's instructions, and it is http://wiki.awesomium.net/general-use/using-web-sessions.html  Did you ever find a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that I got it to flush the values to disk by calling

```
WebCore.Shutdown();
```

When my app is closing.

I'll be doing some more testing on this.